# Random sampling without replacement and independent trials

Tags: statistics

Devore-Berk statistics textbook gives the following heuristics:

> Consider sampling without replacement from a dichotomous population of size $N$. If the sample size (number of trials) $n$ is at most 5% of the population size, the experiment can be analyzed as though it were exactly a binomial experiment.

This means (in my interpretation) is that if we take a sample of size $k$ from a population of size $n$, then, as long as $n \ge 20k$, it doesn't matter if we sample with or without replacement (each trial "an individual is sampled" can be considered independent from the others). Can someone give a probabilistic justification of this fact?

The way I can think of it, the probability of a selecting a particular sample with replacement is $1/n^k$. Without replacement that probability goes up to $1/(n)_k$. So the two situations could be considered "equivalent" if $(n)_k \approx n^k$. But I can't get this from the condition $n \ge αk$.

Comment: k is n, n is N. I don't get why you use $n^k$ and such, since the population is dichotomic. I guess you should take into account at least $p$, the probability of being in group $A$. I don't know the answer, but I would compare the expected values of number of $A$ members. In one case it is of course $np$.

Comment: @Maffred  I was thinking dichotomous in the sense I either select a member of the population to be part of the sample or I don't select it. There are n members, $n^k$ possible sequences (with replacement), $1/n^k$ is the probability of a particular sequence. However I think I was wrong with the other probability, because in this type of iterative process the sample is ordered. I'll edit the post.